# XAML error: Don't know how to detect when ReactiveUI.RoutedViewHost is activated/deactivated

Tags: wpf, xaml, reactiveui

I'm trying to add RoutedViewHost to my View:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyView" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None">
    <rxui:RoutedViewHost x:Name="routedViewHost"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <rxui:RoutedViewHost.DefaultContent>

        </rxui:RoutedViewHost.DefaultContent>
    </rxui:RoutedViewHost>
</Window>
```

But I get an error:

> Don't know how to detect when ReactiveUI.RoutedViewHost is activated/deactivated, you may need to implement IActivationForViewFetcher

And it's unclear what exactly should implement IActivationForViewFetcher.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is likely related to the following bug:

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1696

Is it designer only related?

Comment: Yes. I can actually build that solution.

Comment: Just to let you know this was fixed in RxUI 8.4.1 which was released this morning. Thanks